# How can use static Ip as external-IP at kubernates?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml

I want to set external-Ip as static. I succeed to make  ClusterIP as static but I can not find any solution in anywhere for external_IP.

I use below deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: null
  generation: 1
  labels:
    run: x-master
  name: x-deployment-master
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: x-master
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: x-master
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gitlab:4567/ecoservers/x-docker:x
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: x-master
        volumeMounts:
        - name: task-pv-storage
          mountPath: /opt/y/x/home/configutil
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8009
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8445
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9000
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 7600
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 12001
          protocol: TCP
      volumes:
      - name: task-pv-storage
        hostPath:
          path: /root/configs/configutil_master
          type: Directory
      hostAliases:
      - ip: 10.233.0.13
        hostnames:
        - gessmsatf1
      - ip: 10.233.0.13
        hostnames:
        - gessmsatf2
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: x-master
  name: x-service-master
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/x-service-master
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: "gui-port"
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8443
    targetPort: 8443
  - name: "service-port"
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8445
    targetPort: 8445
  - name: "cu-port"
    protocol: TCP
    port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
  - name: "ajp-port"
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8009
    targetPort: 8009
  - name: "cluster-7600"
    protocol: TCP
    port: 7600
    targetPort: 7600
  - name: "cluster-12001"
    protocol: TCP
    port: 12001
    targetPort: 12001
clusterIP: 10.233.0.13
  loadBalancerIP: 10.233.0.13
  selector:
    run: x-master
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.233.0.13
```

actual result like this:

NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                                      AGE

```
x-service-master  LoadBalancer  10.233.0.13   <pending>    8443:30013/TCP   175m
```

expected result shoul be :
NAME               CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE

```
helloweb           10.31.254.176   203.0.113.32     80:30690/TCP     54s
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes itself does not provide load balancing

[Load Balancing on Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#loadbalancer)

When you specified the service definition you set a type of loadbalancer, which is actually provided by a cloud provider function (Which is most cases is handled by the VPS provider. AWS uses Elastic Load Balancers, Azure uses their TCP Load balancers etc). In those scenarios, you would rarely also specify the IP Address

If you rolled your own Kubernetes on a cloud provider that already offered a service, you're better off just using the service. If you're in a private datacenter, you'll want to deploy metallb and then nat services down to it.

Does using NodePort as the type resolve your issue at all?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes not provide any IP as static IP or external IP. If you are using the AWS, GCP as service you can create service type `LoadBalancer` so it will provide you one external IP that can be used as the external IP adress.

You can also search for ingress in kubernetes.it will also help in future to setup the SSL certificate for your application and multiple website inside one kubernetes cluster.

```
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/
```